# Rationale for DB API 2.0 auto-commit off by default?

Tags: python, transactions, python-db-api

[PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) in the description of [.commit()](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) states:

> Note that if the database supports an auto-commit feature, this must
>   be initially off. An interface method may be provided to turn it back
>   on.

What is the rationale behind that, given that most databases default to auto-commit on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Discovering SQL](http://books.google.com/books?id=HblnED6bKUgC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=sql+standard+implicit+transactions#v=onepage):

> The transaction model, as it is defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL Standard,
>   utilizes the implicit start of a transaction, with an explicit COMMIT, in
>   the case of the successful execution of all the logical units of the
>   transaction, or an explicit ROLLBACK, when the noncommitted changes need to
>   be rolled back (for example, when the program terminates abnormally); most
>   RDBMSs follow this model.

I.e., the SQL standard states transactions should be explicitly committed or
rolled-back.

The case for having explicit committing is best described by [SQL-Transactions](http://myy.haaga-helia.fi/~dbms/dbtechnet/download/SQL-Transactions_Theory%20and%20hands-on%20exercises.pdf#page=8):

> Some DBMS products, for example, SQL Server, MySQL/InnoDB, PostgreSQL and
>   Pyrrho operate by default in the AUTOCOMMIT mode. This means that the result
>   of every single SQL command <strike>will</strike> is automatically committed to the
>   database, thus the effects/changes made to the database by the statement in
>   question cannot be rolled back. So, in case of errors the application needs
>   do reverse-operations for the logical unit of work, which may be impossible
>   after operations of concurrent SQL-clients. Also in case of broken
>   connections the database might be left in inconsistent state.

I.e., error handling and reversal of operations can be vastly simpler when using
using explicit commits instead of auto-committing.

Also, from my observation of the users in the python mailing list, the
consensus was that it is bad for auto-commit to be on by default.

[One post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/db-sig/2000-January/001147.html) states:

> Auto commit is a *bad thing* and a pretty evil invention of ODBC. While it
>   does make writing ODBC drivers simpler (ones which don't support
>   transactions that is), it is potentially dangerous at times, e.g. take a
>   crashing program: there is no way to recover from errors because the
>   database has no way of knowing which data is valid and which is not. No
>   commercial application handling "mission critical" (I love that term ;-)
>   data would ever want to run in auto-commit mode.

[Another post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/db-sig/2000-January/001149.html) says:

> ANY serious application MUST manage its own transactions, as otherwise you
>   can't ever hope to control failure modes.

It is my impression that Python developers took this sort of information into consideration and decided the benefit of having auto-commit off by default (easier error handling and reversing) out weighed that of having auto-commit on (increased concurrency).